# Windows service calling a Windows Forms application - would GUI cause problems?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, windows-services

I have a server application `Server.exe` that listens on a TCP port and replies to clients that connect to it. Currently it is a Windows Forms application with GUI set for debugging (shows who has connected and some other messages).

I would like to make a Windows Service that will start this `Server.exe` and also ensure that the `Server.exe` is always running (restarting it if it crashes for any reason). The service would start a server by creating a new `Process` (of `Server.exe`). The service can be run (and usually is) when no users are logged in. **Since the `Server.exe` does have some GUI, would this create any problems in scenario in which no user is logged in?**

(*I don't care that the GUI won't be visible, I just want to be sure that having GUI does not prevent the app from working properly in context where GUI is not available/visible (i.e. no user is logged in)*).

Note:
The application is not dependent on any specific user input, and it also has some long-running background threads (which also do not depend on user input).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have your design driven by the info/debugging requirements, it might be better if your Windows service itself does all of the work such as port listening and responding. Then have a separate Windows Forms app just for debugging. This app can send info requests to the Windows service on a different port, and display the results.

If you have to stick with the current approach, then you have an issue. The gui process would by default start in session 0. The GUI would display okay, but nobody would ever see it. In Vista and above, no interactive user session has access to session 0.

You could use the [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429) API function to create a process on a specific user's desktop. But that would only work if that specific user is logged-in. And note the caveats stated in that link about user interactions.

Comment: I believe I stated that I don't need to see anything. I don't need the GUI in such case. And there are reasons I avoid putting the logic into the service itself. The only thing I wanted to know is whether the GUI application would run normally in Session 0.

Comment: @Kornelije, yes, in session 0. If nobody ever needs to see the GUI, what's the need for a Windows Forms app?

Comment: so that the debugging and testing will go easier. Debugging services is complicated (bad VS support) and time consuming (need for reinstall after a change). This way when we need to see (for testing) the app, we run it as a normal executable in user environment, and when we don't (in production) it runs in Session 0. I just wanted to make sure the GUI won't make problems. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Kornelije, you can debug a Windows service directly from VS without going through the whole reinstall cycle. Please see my blog entry here: http://sleeksoft.co.uk/public/techblog/articles/20051128_1.html

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible to create an [Interactive Service for Windows, however it is strongly discouraged by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There is a checkbox on LogOn tab of the service property dialog.

The major issue with creating an interactive service is that it is possible to lock the service waiting for user input that will never occur.

However if you want to persue this route then [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is probably a good starting point.